# How to move and object in a straight line with consistent speed

Tags: java

I am trying to move a circle in a straight line. But my Code is not giving expected results. I m using mouseMotionListener to constantly get the target points and x_pos and y_pos are co-ordinated for my circle. I am using trigonometric function sin cos and atan, to move the object in straight line --its a logic i have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732605/moving-an-object-at-a-consistent-speed-from-point-a-to-b) from a question posted on stack overflow--
but it is not giving me the expected results, am i doing something wrong plz help:

```
 import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Snake extends JPanel {
    static Snake snake = new Snake();
    static Co_Ordinates co = new Co_Ordinates();
    static int x_pos = 10, y_pos = 500;
    static int slope;
    int delta_x,delta_y;
    double direction;
    double x_inc,y_inc;
    public Snake() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        g2d.fillArc(x_pos, y_pos, 20, 20, 0, 360);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        /*if(x_pos==co.x_Cur){
            if(co.y_Cur>=y_pos)
                y_pos++;
            else if(co.y_Cur<=y_pos)
                y_pos--;

        }
        else if(y_pos==co.y_Cur){
            if(co.x_Cur>=x_pos)
                x_pos++;
            else if(co.x_Cur<=x_pos)
                x_pos--;

        }
        */
        //slope=((co.y_Cur - y_pos) / (co.x_Cur - x_pos));
        //y_pos = slope*x_pos+y_pos;
        //x_pos++;
        //System.out.println("...");
        if(x_pos!=co.x_Cur&&y_pos!=co.y_Cur){
             int delta_x = co.x_Cur - x_pos;
             int delta_y = co.y_Cur - y_pos;
             direction = Math.atan(delta_y / delta_x); // Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) does the same thing but checks for deltaX being zero to prevent divide-by-zero exceptions
             double speed = 5.0;
             x_inc = (speed * Math.cos(direction));
             y_inc = (speed * Math.sin(direction));
             x_pos+=x_inc;
             y_pos+=y_inc;
        }

        //x_pos = co.x_Cur;
        repaint(10);// parameters
    }

    public void move() {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.add(co);
        jf.addMouseMotionListener(co);
        jf.addMouseListener(co);
        jf.add(snake);
        jf.setSize(600, 600);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class Co_Ordinates extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {


    static int slope;
    static Snake sn = new Snake();
    static int x_Cur=sn.x_pos-20;
    static int y_Cur=sn.y_pos-40;
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        x_Cur = e.getX() - 20;
        y_Cur = e.getY() - 40;

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}// Class Listener ends here
```

Comment: It could be because youre calling `Thread.sleep()` in your `paintComponent()` method. `paintComponent()` runs on the EDT, which handles all swing events, including listener events like MouseEvent. Where are you calling this? (repaint() is what im talking about if thats what youre using). Also, take out all the comments if they arent needed in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code where you used `Math.atan` should be changed to `Math.atan2`.
`atan` only gives angle values between -90deg and 90deg.
`atan2` gives angle values between -180deg and 180deg.

I have modified that part of the code as below.

- First, change `atan` to `atan2`
- Second, make the speed become zero if the circle meets the mouse pointer (the target?)
- Third is a minor one but, you don't need the if-condition unless performance is critical.

Please try with this one.

```
// if(x_pos!=co.x_Cur&&y_pos!=co.y_Cur){
    delta_x = co.x_Cur - x_pos;
    delta_y = co.y_Cur - y_pos;
    direction = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x); 
    double speed = Math.sqrt(delta_x*delta_x + delta_y*delta_y);
    speed = Math.min(speed, 5.0);
    x_inc = (speed * Math.cos(direction));
    y_inc = (speed * Math.sin(direction));
    x_pos+=x_inc;
    y_pos+=y_inc;
//}
```

Comment: Thanx ALooot @Keugyeol , You just solved my problem :D its working perfect.

Comment: Hello @Keugyeol. How can I adjust the speed to the screen resolution? In a multiplayer game walking from point 0 to 1920 should be different then walking from 0 to 800..(both players should finish at the same time).

Comment: @Rey333, Let's define the "unit speed" crossing the screen from left to right at a certain time.
Then the moving speed will be constant regardless of screen resolution.
If the screen were to be traversed in 10 seconds then the unit speed would be 1920/10 or 800/10 depending on screen width.
This unit speed should be multiplied by the delta time between the current and previous frame.
Then the above constant speed (5 pixels) can be replaced by "unit speed" multiplied by "delta time".